# Excel VBA Check Date, Set Date in long format

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. I am trying to learn simple things and I have a specific problem I am trying to figure out.  I get the gist of VBA, however actually trying to put the code into place is driving me crazy. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a date value in cell C2 of 11/24/2015. I want to use VBA to do the following:

a.  Check the active cell to see if the value in the cell is a date.
b.  If it is not a date, display a message that reads "This is not a date".
c.  If it is a date, format the date to display the complete date (day, month,      and year) in the long date format.

This seems simple enough.  I need to use an If Then Else statement and I have been trying different variations of VBA code to get this to work, with no luck. Can you please help me?  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can you at least post the code you have tried? See [IsDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: If IsDate(ActiveCell.Value) <> "a date value" Then
MsgBox "This is not a date", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Hello!!!"
Else
Format ([ActiveCell.Value]), "Long Date")
End If

Answer (score 0):

To check if a value is a date, use the IsDate() function. To format a date a particular way, you can use the Format() function. You can find a reference on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx). In short, you want to use an expression along the lines of:

```
Format([date to format], "Long Date")
```

If you already found these functions and are running into other errors then you should post your code. We cannot debug code that we can't see.

Comment: This is what I have so far, when I try the code line you posted, I receive a message from VB that "expected end of statement."

Comment: If IsDate(ActiveCell.Value) <> "a date value" Then
MsgBox "This is not a date", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Hello!!!"
Else
Format ([ActiveCell.Value]), "Long Date")
End If